# Two routers sharing internet but isolated from each other

Tags: router, internet

I have a router (192.168.6.1) that is connected to the internet modem. Two antennas communicate with each other and the LAN port of the Client antenna is connected to the WAN port of a second router (192.168.0.1).

I can access the internet on the second router without any problem. But the 192.168.0.1 subnet can "see" (ping) the 192.168.6.1 subnet (the opposite does not occur).

How can I isolate 192.168.0.1 subnet too? Is it possible?

A simple flow of the real application is:

```
Modem -> Router 1 (192.168.6.1) -> AP Antenna --------> Client Antenna -> Router 2 (192.168.0.1) -> Network
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the meaning of this setup ??

Comment: The "second" router is not exposing his subnet to the "internet".

Comment: This setup is being made because the "first" router is too far away from the "second" one. Two antennas are connected between them. I need two subnets (one before the antennas - and the antennas -  and another one after this "second" router). But the two subnets must be isolated.

Comment: It does not look like a correct solution for your problem. I would rather divide the subnets at the first router with vlans, putting sort of a switch instead of the router (or using lan ports)

Comment: What do you mean with "antennas between them" ? Didn't you connected a cable to the wan port?

Comment: The antennas are the real application. I am just testing the config using only the two routers. But the problem is the same, using the antennas or using only the two routers. Basically, I am connecting the LAN port of one router to the WAN of the other.

Comment: If I replace the second router by a switch, would it be more correct?

Comment: If you replace the second router with a switch (or you configure the router for processing data like a swtich) you will have all the ips assigned by the first router. Your problem will be no managing vlans to create two different networks

Comment: @LuizS. You can’t use a switch or that would put both “networks” together on the same segment. First, you should update your question so that people have the full picture of what you are trying to accomplish instead of assuming you have the best way figured out and giving us only enough info to meet your end. Don’t daisy chain the networks. Plug the one end of the wireless bridge in to the modem and NOT the LAN port of the first router. It’s effectively the exact same thing I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Plug the WAN port of each router in to a separate port on your modem.

Do not daisy chain them like you have.

Comment: I can't do like this because the "first" router is too far away from the "second" one. So the second one is too far from the modem. I have two antennas between them.

Comment: @LuizS. Physical limitations do not change rules of networking or the answer. If you want two networks isolated DO NOT daisy chain them. Run a wire.

Comment: @LuizS., if you can connect two devices with Wi-Fi, then you do not have a cabling distance limitation. If the distance is over 100 meters, then you cannot use UTP, but you can still use fiber. Fiber can span distances (dozens of kilometers) much farther than Wi-Fi will work.

Answer (score -1):

Please change the setup in modem to bridge mode and add two networks (if it supports)

Present setup :

```
---------------------------    ----------------------   --------------------
| MODEM : N/w: 192.168.6.0 | ---> | Router : 192.168.6.1 | ---> |Router 192.168.0.1|
---------------------------        ----------------------   --------------------
```

Change to

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------       ----------------------    --------------------
| MODEM in Bridge Mode : N/w: 192.168.6.0 & 192.168.0.0 + Add routes| ---> | Router : 192.168.6.1 | ---> |Router 192.168.0.1|
---------------------------------------------------------------------       ----------------------    --------------------
```

OR

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------        ----------      -------------------
| MODEM in Bridge Mode: N/w: 192.168.6.0 & 192.168.0.0 + Add routes| ---> | Switch | ---> |Router 192.168.0.1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------        ----------      --------------------
                                        |
                                        V
                                    ----------------------   
                                    | Router : 192.168.6.1 |
                                    ----------------------
```

Hope this helps.